# How to map an Object's property to another object?

Tags: javascript

I have two objects:

```
objectA = {
   name: 'myname',
   surname: 'mysurname',
   age: 'myage'
}

objectB = {
   birthdate: 'mybirthdate',
   school: 'myschool'
}
```

How can I add `objectA`'s `age` property to `objectB` to get the result below:

```
objectB = {
   birthdate: 'mybirthdate',
   school: 'myschool',
   age: 'myage'
}
```

Comment: `objectB.age = objectA.age`?

Answer (score 1):

There are various ways :

easiest one  :

```js
let obj1 = { food: 'pizza', car: 'ford' }
let obj2 = { animal: 'dog' }
Object.assign(obj1, obj2); //es6

console.log(obj1);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using either:

```
objectB.age = objectA.age
```

or

```
Object.assign(objectB, { age: objectA.age} );
```

Comment: No reason to use the lengthy second one. Especially the assignment is unnecessary.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the object to be a new object (instead of modifying `objectB`), you can use *object rest spread:*

```js
objectA = {
   name: 'myname',
   surname: 'mysurname',
   age: 'myage'
}

objectB = {
   birthdate: 'mybirthdate',
   school: 'myschool'
}

objectC = { ...objectB, age: objectA.age }

console.log(objectC)
```